# Define a suitable threshold to detect only white regions in an image using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, colors, threshold

I am having the following image which has been obtained after performing clustering on the original image. I have tried to define a threshold as shown in the following script.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    img_bgr = cv2.imread('./data/frame.png') 
    img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    

    lower_white = np.array([50,50,150], dtype=np.uint8)
    upper_white = np.array([255,255,255], dtype=np.uint8)
    mask_white = cv2.inRange(img_hsv , lower_white, upper_white)
```

The obtained result is not very satisfactory. Please, how can it be further improved? Any suggestions and comments would be highly appreciated. The image can be found here

[image: Image to be segmented]

Comment: You can add trackbars using `cv.createTrackbar`. [Example](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_trackbar/py_trackbar.html#code-demo). Change the trackbar position untill you reach the goal of the mask. Print those threshold values and use them.

Comment: Thank you sir, I will try and see how it goes

Comment: Don't call anyone sir here. StackOverflow community is as good as your friends and colleagues who helps you out whenever you are stuck. So feel free while using this forum.

Comment: you could show original image, image which you get after running your code and image which you expect.

Comment: Pure white (and black and gray) all have zero saturation. So use a low range of saturation as you "white" is not pure white.